# Hibernate Many to Many linking to existing record

Tags: hibernate, jpa, many-to-many

I have Many to Many relationship between 2 entities: Item and ItemCategory

In class Item

```
@ManyToMany(cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.MERGE})
@JoinTable(
        name="LINK_ITEM_CATEGORY",
        joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="ITEM_ID")},
        inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="CATEGORY_ID")}
        )
private Set<ItemCategory> associatedCategories = new HashSet<ItemCategory>();
```

In class ItemCategory

```
@Column(name="NAME")
private String name;

@ManyToMany(mappedBy="associatedCategories")
private Collection<Item> comprisesExpenditure = new ArrayList<Item>();
```

Whenever I try to save an Item, categories added to Set `associatedCategories` are saved even if a category by the same `name` exists in database. Is there some way for  hibernate to search for Categories based on `name` and create a link with existing one, instead of creating a new Category and linking Item with the new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Since name is not the ID of the category, you may have severa categories with the same name. You might add a unique constraint, but Hibernate can't magically know that the ne category you add in the set should in fact be an existing category having the same name.

When creating categories and adding them to the set, you should search for a category having the same name and, if it exists, put this existing category in the set instead of a new one.

Comment: This worked. I searched for Categories and if found replaced them in the Set associated with the Item. Item and Categories were correctly linked after that with new categories created if not already existing.

Answer (score 2):

To have this working properly you have to implement hashCode and equals methods properly. Without this HashSet may behave unpredicatably.

Comment: Yes, I have implemented them but didn't include them above. But this will guarantee only unique category associated with a particular expenditure. However, I am unable to reuse any category across multiple expenditure.